# cibuildwheel - CIBW_BEFORE_ALL not working as expected and cannot find installed module

Tags: python, github-actions, python-module

Here's the GitHub Actions job that uses to build wheel for a Python module with C++ code, (bound using the `pybind11` module):

```yaml
jobs:
  build_wheels:
    name: Build wheels on ${{ matrix.os }}
    # if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, windows-latest, macos-latest]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install build dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install pybind11 cibuildwheel
      - name: Build wheels
        # uses: pypa/cibuildwheel@v2.8.1
        run: |
          cibuildwheel
```

Related configuration in `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.cibuildwheel]
# before-build = "pip install pybind11"
before-all = "pip install pybind11" <------
test-requires = "pytest"
test-command = "pytest"
```

And it failed with error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pybind11'`, even though it's set to be installed via `CIBW_BEFORE_ALL` option, can you help me figure out why? Thank you in advance.

I read the documentation on [`CIBW_BEFORE_ALL`](https://cibuildwheel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options/#before-all), it says the option `Execute a shell command on the build system before any wheels are built`, so I supposed that it should do the job.

I have included links to the job run's output, the full workflow file, and my setup.py file for reference. I am also including commands I use to build and run locally.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Link to the job run's output](https://github.com/easy-graph/Easy-Graph/actions/runs/3867354850/jobs/6592072102)
[Link to the full workflow file](https://github.com/easy-graph/Easy-Graph/blob/2d702844a4e86538cce5786288c7197e998e698a/.github/workflows/release-cibuildwheel.yaml#L51)
[Link to `setup.py`](https://github.com/easy-graph/Easy-Graph/blob/2d702844a4e86538cce5786288c7197e998e698a/setup.py#L8)

Commands to build and run locally:

```bash
    git clone https://github.com/easy-graph/Easy-Graph && cd Easy-Graph && git checkout pybind11
    pip install pybind11
    python3 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is solved by [Joe Rickerby](https://github.com/joerick) [here](https://github.com/pypa/cibuildwheel/issues/1393#issuecomment-1375315508):

> pybind11 is required by the build, so the right place to specify this requirement is in pyproject.toml, in [build-system.requires](https://cibuildwheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq/#cibw-options-alternatives-deps).

Simply adding the following to pyproject.toml solved this issue:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=42", "wheel", "Cython", "pybind11"]

build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```